# Disable remaining checkboxes when n checkboxes have been checked with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm just starting to learn AngularJS, so bear with me.

I have an app with a list that's bound to an array of objects (D&D spells).  That list displays all the contents of the objects, by binding to the various values of the object.  They filter on the value of a search textbox (`query`) and are sorted by two properties of the spell objects (level and name).  That all works fine.

```
<div ng-repeat="(spellKey, spellValue) in spells | groupBy:'level'">
    <a id="level-{{spellKey}}" class="anchor"></a>
    <div ng-repeat="spell in spellValue | filterEach:query | orderBy:['level','name']">
        <a id="spell-{{spell.name | replaceSpaces}}" class="anchor"></a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a second list that I put in my navbar that's bound to the same array.  It displays just the names and a checkbox next to each name; the checkbox determines whether or not to list each object in the first list (by setting `spell.prepared` to `true` or `false`).  This also works fine.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <form class="form-inline navbar-left col-xs-10" role="search">
        ...
    </form>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <!-- button that displays list of spell links and checkboxes -->
        <button type="button" id="btn-toggle-navbar" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#spell-nav">
            ...
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="spell-nav">
        <div class="checkbox" style="padding-bottom: 4px;">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cbHideNonPrepared" ng-model="hideNonPrepared" />
                Hide non-prepared
            </label>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="(linkKey, linkValue) in spells | groupBy:'level'">
            ...
            <ul style="list-style-type: none">
                <li ng-repeat="spellLink in linkValue" class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="spellLink.prepared" ng-class="{true: 'invis'}[spellLink.alwaysPrepared || spellLink.level == 0]" />
                        <a href="#spell-{{spellLink.name | replaceSpaces}}" ng-click="onSpellLinkClick($event)">{{spellLink.name}}</a>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

...

<!-- previous code block with added 'ng-hide' -->
<div ng-repeat="(spellKey, spellValue) in spells | groupBy:'level'">
    <a id="level-{{spellKey}}" class="anchor"></a>
    <div ng-repeat="spell in spellValue | filterEach:query | orderBy:['level','name']"
         ng-hide="hideNonPrepared && !spell.prepared">
        <a id="spell-{{spell.name | replaceSpaces}}" class="anchor"></a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Last, I want to limit the number of checked checkboxes allowed to some value assigned in `$scope` (happens to be 9, but can be in arbitrary integer).  I also want to exclude any values where `spell.alwaysPrepared == true`, but I assume that's just a `filter` I can add later.

This is where I'm unsure how to continue.  I thought maybe I should set `ng-check`, but I wasn't sure to what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) to disable your checkboxes under certain conditions.

Below is an example of how this might work for you. The key here is to create a function that will be called every digest cycle to determine whether each checkbox should be disabled.

```
angular.module("spells", [])
.controller("spellController", function($scope) {

  $scope.shouldDisable = function(spell) {
    return $scope.numPreparedSpells() == $scope.maxPreparedSpells && !spell.isPrepared;
  };

  $scope.spells = [
    {name: "Magic Missile", isPrepared: false},
    {name: "Lightning bolt", isPrepared: false},
    {name: "Cure Major Wounds", isPrepared: false}
  ];

  $scope.maxPreparedSpells = 2;

  $scope.numPreparedSpells = function() {
    var numPrepared = 0, len = $scope.spells.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if ($scope.spells[i].isPrepared) {
        numPrepared++;
      }
    }

    return numPrepared;
  };
});
```

With this setup in place, your spell list HTML might look like:

```
<div ng-controller="spellController">
  <div ng-repeat="spell in spells">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="spell.isPrepared" ng-disabled="shouldDisable(spell)"/>{{spell.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Try it on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h9kj9mWNvScGjJDooKgx?p=preview).

That showed the basic idea, but it would be nice to have an O(n) solution:

```
angular.module("spells", [])
.controller("spellController", function($scope) {

  $scope.shouldDisable = function(spell) {
    return $scope.numPrepared == $scope.maxPreparedSpells && !spell.isPrepared;
  };

  $scope.spells = [
    {name: "Magic Missile", isPrepared: false},
    {name: "Lightning bolt", isPrepared: false},
    {name: "Cure Major Wounds", isPrepared: false}
  ];

  $scope.maxPreparedSpells = 2;
  $scope.numPrepared = 0;

  $scope.updateNumPreparedSpells = function(spell) {
    if (spell.isPrepared) {
      $scope.numPrepared++;
    }
    else {
      $scope.numPrepared--;
    }
  };
});
```

The trick is to call `updateNumPreparedSpells` every time a checkbox is clicked:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="updateNumPreparedSpells(spell)" ng-model="spell.isPrepared" ng-disabled="shouldDisable(spell)"/>{{spell.name}}
```

Now, the list of spells doesn't need to be traversed to count the number prepared. This, of course, assumes that the prepared state of each spell can *only* be changed by a click on the checkbox. If the data can be changed elsewhere, the count could be incorrect. Such a scenario is comparable to the cache-invalidation problem, which is known to be hard.

Comment: That makes sense.  This is an O(n^2) solution.  Is there an O(n) one?  (`numPreparedSpells()` is being called for every spell in the list; ideally it should be called once per change, and then update based on the result of that call.)

Comment: Good call. I wasn't thinking in terms of performance when I wrote this.